# How spark structured streaming consumers initiated and invoked while reading multi-partitioned kafka topics?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

If a kakfa topic has more than one partition , in java , those many consumer instances/threads would be instantiated at consumer side.

How it could be handled in spark-streaming consumer side ? I dont find much information regarding the same. Any sample for the same i.e. invoking multiple consumers at spark-streaming-consumer of a topic.

Any design suggestion/examples around would be highly thankful.

Regards,
Shyam

Comment: stop using spark email user list to advertise your question please

Comment: @Kiwy sure sir , but what kind email should be send to spark email user list? I am sorry i though it is for spark related questions.

Comment: ask your question to mailing list directly do not use it as a way to increase your view on this site.

Comment: @Kiwy sometime in mails no one responds , I need to duplicate the question in mail and as well as SOF . I have no intention to increase view on site sir. I just need solution if anybody could help .

Answer (score 2):

If *Kafka* has more than one partition that means consumers can benefit from that by doing a certain task in parallel. In particular *spark-streaming* internally can speed up a job by increasing the num-executors parameter. That is tied to the number of partition that Kafka has, **e.g.** if you have the same number of Kafka partition as the num-executors in spark, theoretically all executors could read all partitions at a time, which obviously increase the system throughput.

Comment: thank you for quick reply ... "In particular spark-streaming internally can speed up a job by increasing the num-executors parameter." does it mean I know need to anything with respective to spark-consumer ... i.e. lets say i have 4 partitions in a topic and number of excutors are 10 , then 4 consumers automatically invoked when runing on spark cluster .... I dont need to do any thing @ spark-consumer side.  is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that for example the 6 out of 10 executors will be idle at reading from kafka, however if you repartition your dataset at 10, after reading, than all of them will be involved. As a rule, the number of partition gives you the scale factor, more or less

Answer (score 2):

Spark streaming always reads the data parallelly from all the available partitions in Kafka, as long as spark has enough resources. this comes out of the box with Spark and we don't need write any code for that.

> for example if your Kafka topic has 4 partitions then if you launch
>   your spark job with 2 executors with 2 cores each then your spark job
>   will launch 4 tasks to read the data parallelly from 4 Kafka
>   partitions.

feel free to comment if you need more information.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import java.time.{LocalDate, LocalDateTime}
import java.util.Calendar



object SparkKafka {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("test_app")
      .getOrCreate()
    val sparkContext = spark.sparkContext


    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkContext, Seconds(1)) // the polling frequency is 2 seconds, can be modified based on the BM requirements.
///val currentHour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)

    log.info("Before starting the Stream -->>")
    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String]
      (Array.apply("Kafka_topic_name"), getKafkaParams()))

      .map(record => record.value)

    stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>

      try {
        if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
          log.info("rdd is not empty and saving to -->>"+LocalDate.now.getYear+"/"+LocalDate.now.getMonth+"/"+LocalDate.now.getDayOfMonth+"/"+LocalDateTime.now().getHour)
          rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs:///<folder to save>") //TODO::: Externalize the HDFS location to Props




          LocalDate.now.getMonth


         if (null != args && null != args {
            0
          } && args {
            0
          }.equals("log")) {
            rdd.foreach(x => print("Message read and saved TO S3 bucket----*****--->>" + x))
          }
        }
      } catch {

        case t: Throwable =>
          t.printStackTrace() // TODO: handle error)
          log.error("Exception occured while processing the data exception is {}", t.getCause)
      }
    }

    ssc.start()
    log.info("started now-->> " + compat.Platform.currentTime)
    ssc.awaitTermination()

  }

  def getKafkaParams(): Map[String, Object] = {
    Map[String, Object]("bootstrap.servers" -> "host:port
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "Group_Name",
      //      "sasl.kerberos.service.name" -> "kafka",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (true: java.lang.Boolean))
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you Suresh. how to handle offsets in structured streaming any samples ?

Comment: Spark manages offsets for you. spark stores the offsets in a special topic called `_consumer_offsets`. if your spark job goes down and comes back again , then your job will read the data from where it left last time.

Comment: Happy to share more details, please let me know

Comment: if you want to manage offsets by your self then you have to use either hive or any other persistent store.